# Need to extract a specific record based on record id from an array of Sobject in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, aura, lightning-components

My ask is quite simple here, i have a lightning component where i have an attribute of type Array of Account (Account[]). This array already has a list of Account records. At a certain event (on click of a button), i need to find the account record from the array, corresponding to a record id that i have.

I tried to find a JS method to do so, but couldn’t. Any help here would be appreciated.

Component:
`<aura:attribute name="studentsList" type="Account[]" default="{}"/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) is your friend =)

you simply need to match against your record id:

```
<Array>.find( element => element.id === <yourRecordId>)
```

this will return the first element matching `element.id === <yourRecordId>`

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. This does look like the one, although i just tried to run the following code but it shows 'undefined' in the alert, not sure if i am missing something:

var contextStudent = students.find(element => element.id === accId);
alert(contextStudent);